# How do I search for recipients in Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, search

There are some messages in folders On My Mac in Apple Mail that are from a listserv, so the "to:" field shows "to:list@thislist.com" or whatever. I know that in the headers of the messages, one of them will show my actual e-mail address like this:

`Received: by nz-out-0304.google.com with SMTP id h74so2095083nzf for <myemailaddress@mydomain.com>;`

But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to enter a search string in Mail that will return all the messages that have `myemailaddress@mydomain.com` in the `Received:` field in the headers. Can someone please enlighten me how I can search that (or any other) header field in Mail? This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with making a smart mailbox to see if this is seen as a recipient.

Here's what my attempt looked like:

[image]

From there you can widen the search to Entire message if needed. Since it's not really "To:" you, the normal search keys in the Mail search like **from:xyz** or **to:xyz** won't be of use.

Comment: any recipient doesn't work. I don't understand Apple... why can't they just let you search for any header? Give me a break

Comment: @CommaToast Bummer - I was afraid recipient wouldn't work, but suggested it in case it did. Does widening the search work?

Comment: It appears that Apple Mail just does not have the ability to search any header fields other than the very few that Spotlight can index. Which really irks me.